# Adding header to last column once & checkboxes to certain rows at last column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, foreach

I am having an issue with the above.

I have an input table/form where a user will be making various selections via drop-downs in certain cells and inputting values in others.

For this code, I am working with column B (drop-down selection) and a dynamic last column (checkbox column). The last column will always be dynamic.

Also this is a macro I am calling in a worksheet change event when Column D changes.

**GOAL OF CODE: **

1. Loop through column B

- If cell in Column B has the word "..Add On" (2 out of total possible selections)

2. Apply that value as a new column header at end of table only once (offset last column)

- I am specifying only once as if someone were to select the same option, it just adds it again without verifying the column header already exists.

3. Add header bordering (bottom and right edge)
4. Add a right edge border to column range under header
5. Add checkboxes to the column range

- Only add until last row where Column B is filled (so no checks added when nothing filled out in row)
- And skip the specific rows where Column B value = "..Add-On"

[Example of new header and checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1opjn.png)

I have successfully added the header and bordering when applicable, but have been struggling with how to add the checkboxes correctly. It is adding a checkbox in the correct location (at last column) but only for the "Add On" row and then for the remaining filled out rows in Column B (the ones I would want to apply the checkboxes), it is replacing Column D value with the checkbox.

[Pic of current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS0sK.png)

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsAO As Worksheet
Dim ColD As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim hdrLC As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim cb As Object
Dim rw As Variant
Dim termLR As Long
Dim rowLC As Long
Dim rngAO As Range
Dim cl As Range

Sub Add_AO_Hdr()

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set wsAO = wb.ActiveSheet 
 Set ColD = wsAO.Range("D7:D28")
 hdrLC = wsAO.Cells(6, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 termLR = wsAO.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

 With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    For Each myCell In ColD
        If myCell.Value = "Implant Add On" Or myCell.Value = "RX Add On" Then           
            With wsAO.Cells(6, hdrLC + 1)
                .Value = "Apply " & myCell.Value & " :"           
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 15
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 15
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 15
                
                With Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(22, 0))
                    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).ColorIndex = 15
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 15
                End With
            End With
            
            'Where I am having trouble:
            '--------------------------
            Dim rngRows As Range
            Set rngRows = wsAO.Range("D7:D" & termLR)
    
            For Each rw In rngRows
                If rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "RX Add On" Or rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "Implant Add On" Then Exit For              
                
                If rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value <> "RX Add On" Or rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value <> "Implant Add On" Then
                    rowLC = wsAO.Cells(rw.Row, wsAO.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Set rngAO = wsAO.Range(wsAO.Cells(rw.Row, 1), wsAO.Cells(rw.Row, rowLC))
                                    
                    For Each cl In rngAO
                        Set cb = wsAO.CheckBoxes.Add(cl.left, cl.top, cl.width, cl.height)
                            With cb
                                .LinkedCell = cl.Address
                                .Caption = vbNullString
                                .Value = False
                            End With
                        cl.NumberFormat = ";;;"                       
                    Next cl
                End If
            Next rw
               
        End If
    Next myCell
       
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

For the non-duplicating column headers, I understand I may need to create an array of the header values to compare against my existing headers but am having trouble with finding info that I can understand. I have seen other sources with arrays or application(match) but would like to be pointed in the right direction given I need to add the header once and would like to consider removing the header if the value is null or changed to something else.

---

**BEFORE**

Pic 1) img of what table normally looks like (differs from template to template) without the added column & checkboxes

[See img description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SACdp.png)

**GOAL**

[Intended code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8nOj.png)

---

**EDIT:**

Here are screenshots after running updated code:

1. Pic of checkboxes being added in middle of table
2. Pic of checkbox NOT under newly added column header

[See #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAwI.png)
[See #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9jsq.png)

Please don't pay attention to weird decimal number/blank column in gray. I am working on a test ws that would be automating that info when running through the workbook.

Comment: All those Global variables make it very difficult to review your code - we have no idea how they're populated or with what values.  `Application.Match()` would likely be the fastest way to check for any existing matching header.

Comment: Sorry, these variables are only used in this sub and 1 other in the same module. I was  planning to refer to them in a separate sub for removing headers and checkboxes. I also updated the code as I forgot the variables descriptions!

Comment: But thank you for the advice on Application.Match(). Will do more research on that!

Comment: `If rw.Cells(r, 2).Value = "RX Add On"` - you don't have a variable `r` declared...

Comment: That was also unintentionally mistyped. I have corrected the code to the version I am using!

Comment: Why is your outer loop looping over Column D?  Your description has Column B...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I updated it to reflect Column D and I re-ran given that update and it's almost working? It is populating a checkbox at the end but for the filled out row(s) that aren't "Add On" (yay!) but it still is populating the checkbox in lieu of the Column D "Add On" value. Also, the checkbox is not right under the last column header like I hoped but I'm attaching screenshots to the post!

Comment: Honestly I'm having problem following exactly what is supposed to happen when your code runs.  It would be very useful to provide example "before" and "after" screenshots (preferably including row/column headers)

Comment: Images and comments added to post. Let me know if i can provide anything else!

Comment: Sorry I mean "how your sheet looks before the code runs" and "how you *want* it to look after the code runs" I want to figure out what your code is *intended* to do.  Include the column headers "A", "B" etc so we can see where things are on the sheet.

Comment: ...also maybe useful to explain when/how the code is to be triggered.  From a change event, or run manually for example?

Comment: Ok added new pic of intended results. Also this sub is expected to be called during a worksheet change event whenever Column D changes. And Column B in the range wasn't supposed to be there as I was previously working off of it but focused to Col D cause I was already looping through it.

Comment: In that case do you need to account for the case where "xxx Add On" had been selected but got de-selected?  Can there by multiple rows where "xxx Add On" has been seelected?

Comment: Sorry just saw your comment. And if I'm understanding your question, i do still need to worry about removing the header and removing/deselecting the checkboxes when deselected from Column D but was mostly focused on getting it to show up at all!

Comment: And yes! There's another drop down of "RX Add On" that could be selected and then a new column header  and checkboxes  would be added if not there at the end of the table. That's why I've left it dynamic. I don't know if the user will even select that option in the table and if they do, then it just adds on to the existing template as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what [I think] you're describing.  Works in my light testing...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_AO_Hdr()

    Const HEADERS_ROW As Long = 6

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsAO As Worksheet, ColD As Range, c As Range
    Dim v, hdr, mRows, mHdr, colNum As Long, arrAddOns, term, cb As Object, rngCB As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsAO = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set ColD = wsAO.Range("D7:D28")
    
    arrAddOns = Array("Implant Add On", "RX Add On") 'terms to check for
    
    For Each term In arrAddOns
       
        hdr = HeaderText(term)                    'get the header text
        mHdr = Application.Match(hdr, wsAO.Rows(HEADERS_ROW), 0) 'matching header?
        
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(term, ColD, 0)) Then 'term exists in ColD?
            If IsError(mHdr) Then 'not yet a matching header: add it...
                mHdr = wsAO.Cells(HEADERS_ROW, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                With wsAO.Cells(HEADERS_ROW, mHdr)
                    .Value = hdr
                    'snipped formatting/border code
                End With
            End If
            'add/remove checkboxes if needed
            For Each c In wsAO.Range("D7:D" & wsAO.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
                Set rngCB = c.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr)
                Set cb = CellCheckbox(rngCB) 'get any existing checkbox for this cell
                Debug.Print rngCB.Address, Not cb Is Nothing
                If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, arrAddOns, 0)) Then 'not an "add on" term
                    If cb Is Nothing Then AddCheckbox rngCB 'add checkbox if needed
                Else
                    If Not cb Is Nothing Then cb.Delete 'delete any checkbox
                End If
            Next c
        Else
            'term doesn't exist in ColD: remove any matched column and checkboxes
            If Not IsError(mHdr) Then
                For Each c In ColD.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr).Cells
                    On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if no matching checkbox
                    CellCheckbox(c).Delete
                    On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors
                Next c
                wsAO.Columns(mHdr).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next term
End Sub

'given a term, return the text for the column header
Function HeaderText(term) As String
    HeaderText = "Apply " & term & " :"
End Function

'add a linked checkbox to a cell
Sub AddCheckbox(c As Range)
    Dim cb As Object
    Set cb = c.Worksheet.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height)
    With cb
        .LinkedCell = c.Address
        .Caption = vbNullString
        .Value = False
    End With
    c.NumberFormat = ";;;"
End Sub

'if a cell has a linked checkbox, return it
Function CellCheckbox(c As Range) As Object
    Dim cb As Object
    For Each cb In c.Worksheet.CheckBoxes
        If cb.LinkedCell = c.Address Then
            Set CellCheckbox = cb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cb
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting back to you but I've been able to test it and it's working great so far, thanks so much! You've really saved me so much time and stress, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Good to hear it's working out for you.

Comment: I'm sure you hear this a lot but it means so much in all the ways you help and you inspire me to keep going and be a better coder!