# VBA - Unknown variable error during column/checkbox/row removal (prev working code)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, checkbox, variable-assignment

I was graciously helped with a past question (see: [Adding header to last column once & checkboxes to certain rows at last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367385/adding-header-to-last-column-once-checkboxes-to-certain-rows-at-last-column/76369472?noredirect=1#comment134696497_76369472)) and now that I am adding to it, I am getting variable errors and can't figure out how to resolve it.

---

Current goal of code:

1. Compare an array to a range in hidden admin ws (range is of listbox selections - up to 4 selections allowed)
2. If applicable selection made (& recorded in hidden ws), will be compared to

   Table 1) a table's headers to see if a new column header (& bordering & checkboxes) needs to be added at end of table
   [Img of Table 1 w/ added columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUmRB.png)

   Table 2) another table's (different ws) rows in a single column to see if new row/line item needs to be added into table
   [Img of Table 2 w/ added rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JANw0.png)

Also, if a user goes back to the source listbox and deselects an item, it will impact the 2 tables:

```
  Table 1) applicable table header and assoc. column & checkboxes removed 
  Table 2) applicable row/line item removed from table
```

---

Issue:

The addition into the tables works great but I am having trouble during what would be the "removal" process. I have updated the code since being helped (added to it) but stayed with the recommended structure.

I started with the c variable as Range, but tried out Long/Variant just to see what I would get and see if I can understand what's happening but nothing that I understand at this point.

Various variable errors:

[Error 1) Object variable or With Block variable not set - when variable "c" is Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9BNa.png)

[runtime error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFOtq.png)

[Error 2) control variable must be Variant or Object - when variable "c" is Long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojgi7.png)

[Error 3) ByRef argument type mismatch - when variable "c" is Variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1UaD.png)

---

CODE:

```
Sub IP_AO_Update()

    Const AO_COL As Long = 4
    Const HEADERS_ROW As Long = 6
    
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim aWS As Worksheet
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Dim SelTerm As Variant
    Dim mSel As Variant
    Dim c As Variant 'Long 'Range
    Dim bLR As Long
    Dim dLR As Long
    Dim arrSel As Variant
    Dim colD As Range
    Dim targetLR As Long
    Dim arrAddOns As Variant
    Dim term As Variant
    Dim hdr As Variant
    Dim mHdr As Variant
    Dim rngCB As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set aWS = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set targetWS = wb.Sheets(aWS.Index + 1)
    Set admin = wb.Worksheets("Admin")
    Set SelRng = admin.Range("AF2:AF5")
    Set colD = targetWS.Range("D7:D10")
      
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    arrAddOns = Array("Implant Add On", "High Cost Drug Add On", "Postpartum LARC Add On", "Renal Dialysis Add On")
    
    For Each term In arrAddOns
       
        'Apply [AO]:'
        hdr = HeaderText(term)
        mHdr = Application.Match(hdr, aWS.Rows(HEADERS_ROW), 0)
        
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(term, SelRng, 0)) Then
        
            If IsError(mHdr) Then
            
                ' + AO hdr          
                mHdr = aWS.Cells(HEADERS_ROW, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                
                ' + AO col bordering
                With aWS.Cells(HEADERS_ROW, mHdr)
                    .Value = hdr
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 15
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 15
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 15
                    With Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(22, 0))
                        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
                        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).ColorIndex = 15
                        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
                        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 15
                        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
                        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 15
                    End With
                End With
                
                ' + AO terms in AO ws
                mSel = targetWS.Cells(Rows.Count, AO_COL).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                             
                With targetWS
                    .Cells(mSel, AO_COL).Value = term
                                    
                    If .Cells(mSel, AO_COL).Value <> "" Then
                        .Cells(mSel, 2).Value = "ADD ON"
                    End If
                End With
            End If
                  
            ' + cb
            For Each c In aWS.Range("B7:B" & aWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
                Set rngCB = c.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr)
                Set cb = CellCheckbox(rngCB)
                Debug.Print rngCB.Address, Not cb Is Nothing
                
                If cb Is Nothing Then AddCheckbox rngCB
            Next c
            
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Else
            If Not IsError(mHdr) Then
                For Each c In colD.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr).Cells 
                    On Error Resume Next
                    
                    ' - tbl AO hdr, cols, cb
                    CellCheckbox(c).Delete  'The c variable starts to error here when c = Range
                    c.ClearContents
                    c.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
                    c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
                    c.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    
                    With Range(c.Offset(1, 0), c.Offset(22, 0))
                        c.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
                        c.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
                    End With
                    
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next c
                
                aWS.Columns(mHdr).Delete
                
                ' - rows in AO ws
                With targetWS
                    For Each c In colD.EntireColumn.Rows(mSel).Cells
                        c.ClearContents
                    Next c
                    
                    .Rows(mSel).Delete
                    
                End With
            End If
        
        End If
    Next term
End Sub
```

---

EDIT 1

[Img of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wSy.png)

EDIT 2

[Img of results - checkbox remaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wPVJ.png)

Comment: Having received a runtime error with a correctly declared variable, you started changing its type randomly in the hope that is the way to fix it, understandably receiving *compile* time errors instead?

Comment: I should have mentioned that but that's exactly what happened!

Comment: So make the variable what it was before and start looking for why you are accessing it when it's (likely correctly) `Nothing`. Your screenshot does not even show where the *runtime* error is.

Comment: I updated the post to include tan img of point of the error.

Comment: You have `On Error Resume Next` so presumably you mean to ignore any errors in that section.  So if you're getting a run-time error there it's probably because you have your VBA error handling option set to "Break on All Errors".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, hadn't heard of that before. I updated that setting and the code ran for the most part! However, the checkbox isn't deleting when the column it belonged to got deleted?

Comment: `For Each c In colD.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr).Cells`  - here `colD` is on `targetWS`, but your checkboxes are on `aWS`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - the issue is here:

`For Each c In colD.EntireRow.Columns(mHdr).Cells`

`colD` is on `targetWS`, but your checkboxes are on a different worksheet `aWS`.

---

Instead of using `On Error resume Next` consider adding a Sub like this:

```
'Delete any checkbox linked to cell `c`
Function DeleteLinkedCheckbox(c As Range)
    Dim cb As Object
    Set cb = CellCheckbox(c)
    If Not cb Is Nothing Then cb.Delete
End Function
```

Then instead of this:

```
On Error Resume Next
CellCheckbox(c).Delete  
c.ClearContents
'...
'...
On Error Got 0
```

You can call

```
DeleteLinkedCheckbox c
c.ClearContents
'etc
```

Comment: Implemented the code above and it looks like it's skipping over the checkbox deletion portion?  Like I ran it as is (checkbox removal + ) and with just the  .ClearContents/Delete (excluding checkbox removal code) with the same results:

Comment: I've included img of results in the post!

Comment: If it's skipping that then you'd need to step through the code and figure out what line is the issue.  It's too difficult for me to troubleshoot without the workbook so I can run it in context.  Let me know if you're able to share it, and I'll drop my email here.

Comment: I should be able to if you're okay to look at it!

Comment: Got it thanks! you should see msg in a moment

Comment: Also check the file I sent you - may have ended up in your Spam folder.